# Jquery - Reuse Function Multiple Times With One Dynamic Value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

**NOTE:** Here is a working example of the page on my website. Currently it only works for the DayZ section. https://www.brotherhoodgaming.net/reddit.php

**EDIT:**
Here is my HTML for the click redditHeader

```
<div class="redditHeader grey3">
        <p class="white floatleft">
            DayzUnderground
        </p>
        <i class="material-icons redditHeaderCollapse">
            arrow_drop_down
        </i>
    </div>
```

With the help of StackOverflow over the last few months I have built the skeleton of my first website.I have a massive Jquery JSON function that pulls data from reddit based on the URL of the subreddit. I also have 3 `<div>`'s (**Dayz**, **BuildaPCSales** and **Bronies** as a test).

[image]

When I click on any of those bars I would like my Javascript function to dynamically load data from `'https://www.reddit.com/r/' + encodeURIComponent(subreddit) + '.json'` - with (subreddit) being the val() text of the `<div>`. In this example, if I click on "Dayz" I want the reddit to load data from `r/dayz.json` without having to manually type the URL into the code.

Here is my javascript function. It currently works, successfully, for any reddit that I manually type the URL for.

```
<script>
$('.redditHeader').click(function() {
    var subreddit = $(this).children('.redditBanner').text();
    loadRedditData(subreddit);
});

function loadRedditData(subreddit) {
    $.getJSON('https://www.reddit.com/r/' + encodeURIComponent(subreddit) + '.json').then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        function foo(data) {
            $.each(
                // iterate over 10 children, starting at the 0th index
                data.data.children.forEach(foo); function foo(item, index) { //SAYS I AM MISSING A ")" HERE
                    //Load reddit title in correct div//
                    $('#news' + i + ' .redditTitle').append(
                        $('<a>')
                            .attr('href', 'https://m.reddit.com/' + post.data.permalink)
                            .text(post.data.title)
                    );

                    //Load reddit Score (net UP - DOWN)//
                    $('#news' + i + ' .redditScore').prepend(
                        $('<p>')
                            .attr('class', 'redditUpvoteScore')
                            .text(post.data.score)
                    );

                    //Load reddit post-text in HTML format//
                    $('#news' + i + ' .redditPost').append(
                        $('<p>')
                            .text(post.data.selftext_html)
                    );

                    //Load sub-reddit name in HTML format//
                    /*$('#news' + i + ' .subRedditName').append(
                     $('<p>')
                     .attr('class', 'subRedditFormat')
                     .text('r/' + post.data.subreddit)
                     );*/

                    //Load post thumbnail URL into an <a> tag wrapping the image//
                    $('#news' + i + ' .redditThumbnail').append(
                        $('<a>')
                            .attr('href', post.data.url)
                            .attr('class', 'thumbURL')
                    );

                    //Load actual thumbnail into the <a> wrapper tag with the thumbURL class//
                    $('#news' + i + ' .thumbURL').append(
                        $('<img>')
                            .attr('src', post.data.thumbnail)
                            .attr('class', "image news hide floatleft")
                    );

                    //Load reddit Username and URL into container DIV//
                    $('#news' + i + ' .userNameContainer').append(
                        $('<a>')
                            .attr('class', 'redditUserName')
                            .attr('href', 'https://m.reddit.com/user/' + post.data.author)
                            .text(post.data.author)
                    );

                    // Convert post creation time to local time//
                    var utcSeconds = post.data.created_utc;
                    var d = new Date(0);
                    // The 0 is the key, which sets the date to the epoch
                    d.setUTCSeconds(utcSeconds);

                    //Use Moment.js to calculate relative date and append to DIV//
                    $('#news' + i + ' .redditDate').append(
                        moment(d).fromNow()
                    );

                    //Decodes HTML into correct format by replacing unescaped characters//
                    $('.redditPost').each(function(){
                        var $this = $(this);
                        var t = $this.text();
                        $this.html(t.replace('&lt','<').replace('&gt', '>'));
                        $this.html(t.replace('null','').replace('null', ''));
                    });

                    //Checks for "self" tagged images and replaces with placeholder image//
                    function changeSourceAll() {
                        var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
                        for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                            if (images[i].src.indexOf('self') !== -1) {
                                images[i].src = images[i].src.replace("self", "css/images/default.jpg");
                            }
                        }
                        for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                            if (images[i].src.indexOf('default') !== -1) {
                                images[i].src = images[i].src.replace("self", "css/images/default.jpg");
                            }
                        }
                        for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                            if (images[i].src.indexOf('https://www.brotherhoodgaming.net/default') !== -1) {
                                images[i].src = images[i].src.replace("https://www.brotherhoodgaming.net/default", "css/images/default.jpg");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    changeSourceAll();
                }
            )
        }
    });
}
```

And here was my terrible attempt to pull the value of the text from the `<div>`'s with class "redditHeader".

```
$('.redditHeader').each().on('click', function (){
$('p[class="white"]').val();
})
```

Thanks in advance for any possible help on this. Im stumped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get `.val()` of a `<p>` tag! Use `.text()`!

```js
$('.redditHeader').click(function() {
  var subreddit = $(this).children('.white').text();
  loadRedditData(subreddit);
});
```

Comment: This is perfect, the two of you have solved my primary issue. I just tested it in the console. My last question is, now that it's pulling the JSON data it doesn't seem to be performing the rest of the function (appending it to the DIVs). Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @DavidWashburn trying changing the way you loop. Try.. `data.data.children.forEach(foo); function foo(item, index) { .. }`

Comment: That looks much closer to what I want, rather than forcing 10 iterations I want it to keep looping until it runs out of DIV's to place them in. However when I put this code in it says I'm missing a ")" but I don't see any obvious places where that might be. I've updated my main page to show the new Javascript. Sorry, I'm a huge Javascript beginner, this project is probably slightly over my head.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that should work :

```
$('.redditHeader').click(function (event){
    var subreddit = $(event.currentTarget).find('.white').text();
    loadRedditData(subreddit);
 })
```

The $(event.currentTarget) get the element that have been clicked on and find() will get the child of this element. Finally, I call loadRedditData(subreddit).

I suppress the each() because I don't really understand what you try to achieve with it.

Comment: When I click I get an "undefined.json". It seems to be having trouble reading the text. I have updated the post with my HTML to show you what I have. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: I just edited. val() is only for input and after seeing your html $(event.currentTarget) or $(this) is better.